# possible to join/attach Konsole windows?

Tags: kde, window, konsole

In KDE's Konsole, if I have a Konsole window open with multiple tabs and accidentally click and drag a tab off into its own window, is there any way to re-attach it to the tabs of the original Konsole window? I've tried dragging it back onto the window and holding down different keys, but I can't figure out a way to do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can not tell if and when this changed, but with Konsole 20.08.1 (I could test it on Arch Linux), detached tabs can be re-attached to their original window by:

1. Dragging them by their label in the tab bar.

   [image]

   To see the tab bar in windows containing one tab only, you may need to set:
   "Configure Konsole" > "Tab Bar / Splitters" > "Appearance" > "Show: Always"
2. Dropping them anywhere on the target window, except for its title bar.

This will also work for newly created windows (i.e. for tabs that had not been previously detached) if "Configure Konsole" > "General" > "Run all Konsole windows in a single process" is checked (except for windows opened before this settings was applied).

Comment: Since I do prefer not to use the "Show Always" option, but instead "Show TabBar when needed", I usually just open a new tab if I have a single tab  open (`Ctrl + Shift + N`), and then drag the old tab to the window where I want to place it. Then I have to close the other window.  I would prefer if I could drag the window title into the tab bar.

Comment: In Konsole 19.12.3 I found that I can detach a Konsole tab and re-attach it to the same Konsole window, but I can't attach it to a different Konsole window.

Comment: @raphael75 Is "Run all Konsole windows in a single process" checked in your Konsole settings? Maybe I wasn't really clear, but that part of my answer means that, if that option is not set (as in the default configuration, I believe), attaching tabs to a different window is not possible.

Comment: I just filed a bug report about this. This would be a great feature to have.

Comment: @raphael75 can you past the link to the bug report here please - I would love to follow the discussion.

Comment: Here is a related bug report: https://invent.kde.org/utilities/konsole/-/issues/6
Unfortunately it was closed with the fix of removing the `Ctrl + L` shortcut w/o addressing the underlying problem

Comment: @ChristianHerenz Here it is! https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438740